# PySpark casting confusion - column not casting to Double, despite not complaining on cast

Tags: python, pyspark, casting

I'm trying to plot some data that currently exists in a PySpark dataframe - however, to get to the point where I can plot it, I need to cast one of the columns from a string to a `DoubleType`. Normally isn't an issue, but the cast isn't working as expected:

```
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

    spark_session = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

    properties = {
        "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver",
        "user": os.environ['POSTGRES_USERNAME'],
        "password": os.environ['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'],
        "currentSchema": 'heart'
    }

    df = spark_session.read.jdbc(
        url=f"jdbc:postgresql://{os.environ['POSTGRES_IP']}/fitbit",
        properties=properties,
        table='daily',
    )

    print(df.dtypes)
    ### DataFrame[summary: string, type: string, minutes: string, calories: string, resting_heart_rate: string]

    changed_df = df.withColumn('double_type_calories', df.calories.cast("double"))
    print(changed_df.dtypes)
    ### DataFrame[summary: string, type: string, minutes: string, calories: string, resting_heart_rate: string, double_type_calories: string]
```

This behavior occurs however I try the cast - `.cast(DoubleType())`, etc. - so that would be what I've tried to solve it thus far.  I imagine it must just be a small logical mistake I'm making that I'm overlooking, but can't quite ID it.  Any ideas from you lovely people?!

edit: Some example data:

first DF:

```
Row(type='Peak', minutes=Decimal('0.00000'), date=datetime.date(2020, 8, 31), calories=Decimal('0.00000'), resting_heart_rate=64)
Row(type='Fat Burn', minutes=Decimal('99.00000'), date=datetime.date(2020, 9, 1), calories=Decimal('656.89600'), resting_heart_rate=66)
Row(type='Peak', minutes=Decimal('0.00000'), date=datetime.date(2020, 9, 1), calories=Decimal('0.00000'), resting_heart_rate=66)
Row(type='Fat Burn', minutes=Decimal('211.00000'), date=datetime.date(2020, 9, 2), calories=Decimal('1128.23185'), resting_heart_rate=68)
Row(type='Peak', minutes=Decimal('0.00000'), date=datetime.date(2020, 9, 2), calories=Decimal('0.00000'), resting_heart_rate=68)
```

second DF:

```
Row(type='Peak', minutes=Decimal('0.00000'), date=datetime.date(2020, 8, 31), calories=Decimal('0.00000'), resting_heart_rate=64, double_type_calories=0.0)
Row(type='Fat Burn', minutes=Decimal('99.00000'), date=datetime.date(2020, 9, 1), calories=Decimal('656.89600'), resting_heart_rate=66, double_type_calories=656.896)
Row(type='Peak', minutes=Decimal('0.00000'), date=datetime.date(2020, 9, 1), calories=Decimal('0.00000'), resting_heart_rate=66, double_type_calories=0.0)
Row(type='Fat Burn', minutes=Decimal('211.00000'), date=datetime.date(2020, 9, 2), calories=Decimal('1128.23185'), resting_heart_rate=68, double_type_calories=1128.23185)
Row(type='Peak', minutes=Decimal('0.00000'), date=datetime.date(2020, 9, 2), calories=Decimal('0.00000'), resting_heart_rate=68, double_type_calories=0.0)
```

Comment: does it make a difference if you load your data from somewhere else instead from the database?

Comment: I created a CSV file with the same data, and it was also read in as all strings - whether I had `inferSchema` set to true or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I think its because of `df.describe()`

`df.describe()` computes statistics for numeric and string columns. This includes count, mean, stddev, min, and max. You can do `df.describe.show()` to see them. It always returns column datatypes as `string`

To check the data types of your `df`, use `df.printSchema` or `df.dtypes`

Your casting is correct. `changed_df.dtypes` should show `double` for `double_type_calories`

Comment: Same output as is in the original question, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is because of `describe()`. What do you see when you do: `df.withColumn('double_type_calories', col("calories").cast("double")).dtypes`

Comment: you're correct, dtypes does show the expected output. Unfortunately, I still get the initial error that led me to post the question - the data doesn't plot because of a ```TypeError: no numeric data to plot``` - which seems to conflict with what `dtypes` is telling me.  I think this might be a different issue than what I thought it was..